# Fish-shell not recognizing .bashrc exports

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, fish

I had to install a couple of programs for my university on Ubuntu, those required extra lines in `.bashrc` these are the following lines

```
if [ -d /opt/pic32mx/bin ] ; then
 export PATH=$PATH:/opt/pic32mx/bin
fi 

export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar:/usr/local/lib/ST-4.3.1.jar:"
export ANTLR4_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

It seems that fish-shell won't recognize these exports and therefore won't run the commands, I have to go to my bash if I want to run it.
Is there a simple solution so fish recognizes the commands and works fine just like my bash?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking `fish`? are you starting an interactive bash shell, and starting `fish` from there?

Comment: end of *export CLASSPATH=* typo ? the line is chopped.

Comment: @steeldriver when I open my terminal it's already on fish-shell

Comment: @bac0n fixed, but that's beside the point, the export is already working on bash but not on fish

Comment: should probably not be a colon at the end, a bit skeptical, using *dot* in an export too.

Comment: @bac0n the code is correct, but I will say again. That's beside the point, that code is from `.bashrc` and the export is working for normal bash! But fish won't recognize it

Comment: @AndréClérigo so... you changed your *login shell* to `fish` (as shown in the output of `getent passwd $USER` for example)? in that case, your .bashrc is likely not involved at all.

Comment: ... [How do I run a command every login? What's fish's equivalent to .bashrc or .profile?](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-run-a-command-every-login-what-s-fish-s-equivalent-to-bashrc-or-profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fish uses [the `set` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html) for setting variables.

Also, the recently added [`fish_add_path`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html) command works for adding directories to PATH. If you have an older version of fish, use the `fish_user_paths` directory as described [in the tutorial](https://fishshell.com//docs/3.1/tutorial.html?highlight=fish_user_paths#path).

Note that fish does interesting things with [variables that end with *PATH](https://fishshell.com//docs/3.1/index.html#variables-path)  -- it assumes that other processes want a colon-separated list of directories, so that's what it provides:

```
$ set -gx FOO_PATH foo bar baz

$ set --show FOO_PATH
$FOO_PATH: set in global scope, exported, a path variable with 3 elements
$FOO_PATH[1]: |foo|
$FOO_PATH[2]: |bar|
$FOO_PATH[3]: |baz|

$ bash -c 'declare -p FOO_PATH'
declare -x FOO_PATH="foo:bar:baz"
```

---

The solution is to translate the bash commands to fish commands, and store them in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```
if [ -d /opt/pic32mx/bin ] 
  set fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /opt/pic32mx/bin
end 

set -gx CLASSPATH   . /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar /usr/local/lib/ST-4.3.1.jar ""
set -gx ANTLR4_PATH /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quick understand it, the `.bashrc` code was written automatically and I don't know nothing about it. What does this mean for me? What can I do, for the generic answer you gave me I can't understand anything because I really don't know much about shell

Comment: If you want to get comfortable in fish, read something about it: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html particularly https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html